# How to push multiple branchs to multiple repository via vscode

Tags: git, github-actions, githooks

I have a repo with 3 branches named 1,2,3, and a public GitHub repository named A, a private GitHub repository named B, a GitLab repository named C.
The branch 3 is private.

So I want VSCode do this for me when I click the push button.

- push branch 1,2 to A,B,C
- push branch 3   to B,C

GitHub marketplace provides a lot of sync action, but the `.workflow` folder will also be synced to public repository, or commit SHA from different repository will not match if I exclude the folder in action.

It works just fine through `git remote set-url --add --push` except branch 3 is also pushed.

I think git pre-push hook might work, but how to distinguish which branch is current branch and what will happen if I use `git push --all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works just fine through `git remote set-url --add --push` except branch 3 is also pushed

It should not, since you can list the repositories you want to push for each branch.

For instance, assuming 3 repositories:

```bash
git remote add A https://github.com/username/repoA.git
git remote add B https://github.com/username/repoB.git
git remote add C https://gitlab.com/username/repoC.git
```

You can configure each branch:

```bash
# Configure remote A
git remote set-url --add --push A https://github.com/username/repoA.git
git remote set-url --add --push A https://github.com/username/repoB.git
git remote set-url --add --push A https://gitlab.com/username/repoC.git

# Configure remote B
git remote set-url --add --push B https://github.com/username/repoA.git
git remote set-url --add --push B https://github.com/username/repoB.git

# Configure branch 1
git config --local "branch.branch1.remote" A
git config --local "branch.branch1.merge" refs/heads/branch1
git config --local "branch.branch1.push" refs/heads/branch1

# Configure branch 2
git config --local "branch.branch2.remote" A
git config --local "branch.branch2.merge" refs/heads/branch2
git config --local "branch.branch2.push" refs/heads/branch2

# Configure branch 3
git config --local "branch.branch3.remote" B
git config --local "branch.branch3.merge" refs/heads/branch3
git config --local "branch.branch3.push" refs/heads/branch3
```

A push while a branch is checked out should push that branch to the right repositories.

However, the "`Synchronize Changes`" button and "`Git: Push`" command in VSCode push only the *current* branch.

You might need to create a custom task to achieve what you want (one push for all three branches)

- Open the Command Palette with Ctrl+Shift+P (or Cmd+Shift+P on macOS), type "`Tasks: Open User Tasks`", and press Enter
- Select "Other"
- Replace the content of the tasks.json with:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "push-all-branches",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "git checkout branch1 && git push && git checkout branch2 && git push && git checkout branch3 && git push",
      "group": "none",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That way, you have a "`push-all-branches`" new command.

Note that you cannot directly associate a custom task to the "`Synchronize Changes`" button in Visual Studio Code, because it is hard-coded to perform the "`Git: Sync`" command, which fetches and pushes changes only for the *current* branch.

You could create a custom keyboard shortcut to run the "push-all-branches" task quickly, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it seems not working on my computer. I will publish my `.git/config` file after run above commands.

Answer (score 0):

Content of my `.git/config` after execute commands provided by VonC.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "A"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/A/*
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch1:refs/heads/branch1
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch2:refs/heads/branch2
[remote "B"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repoB.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/B/*
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch1:refs/heads/branch1
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch2:refs/heads/branch2
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch3:refs/heads/branch3
[remote "C"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/username/repoC.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/C/*
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch1:refs/heads/branch1
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch2:refs/heads/branch2
    pushurl = refs/heads/branch3:refs/heads/branch3
[branch "branch1"]
    remote = A
    merge = refs/heads/branch1
[branch "branch2"]
    remote = A
    merge = refs/heads/branch2
[branch "branch3"]
    remote = B
    merge = refs/heads/branch3
```

And when I check out a branch and run `git push`, I got error like this.

```
fatal: 'refs/heads/branch1:refs/heads/branch1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't know why this happend. But this lead me to file `.git/config`. After
looking deeper into it, I modified my `.git/config` to this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "private"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    fetchurl = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/private/*
    pushurl = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    pushurl = https://github.com/username/repoB.git
[remote "public"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    fetchurl = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/public/*
    pushurl = https://github.com/username/repoA.git
    pushurl = https://github.com/username/repoB.git
    pushurl = https://gitlab.com/username/repoC.git
[branch "branch1"]
    remote = public
    merge = refs/heads/branch1
    push = refs/heads/branch1
[branch "branch2"]
    remote = public
    merge = refs/heads/branch2
    push = refs/heads/branch2
[branch "branch3"]
    remote = private
    merge = refs/heads/branch3
    push = refs/heads/branch3
```

And this works for me.

P.S. command result by `git branch -avv`

```
PS C:\Repo> git branch -avv
* branch2                       e447c9a [public/branch2] fix: msg1
  branch3                       1a2dd91 [private/branch3] fix: msg2
  branch1                       167db89 [public/branch1] msg4
  remotes/repoB/branch2         df83934 feat: msg3
  remotes/repoB/branch3         1a2dd91 fix: msg2
  remotes/repoB/branch1         167db89 msg4
  remotes/repoC/branch2         e447c9a fix: msg1
  remotes/repoC/branch3         1a2dd91 fix: msg2
  remotes/repoC/branch1         167db89 msg4
  remotes/repoA/branch2         df83934 feat: msg3
  remotes/repoA/branch1         167db89 msg4
  remotes/private/branch2       e447c9a fix: msg1
  remotes/private/branch3       1a2dd91 fix: msg2
  remotes/private/branch1       167db89 msg4
  remotes/public/branch2        e447c9a fix: msg1
  remotes/public/branch3        1a2dd91 fix: msg2
  remotes/public/branch1        167db89 msg4
```

Comment: Thanks for @VonC once again. And if anyone knows why I got that error please leave a comment.

Comment: Can you add the output of `git branch -avv`?

Comment: My git version is `git version 2.37.3.windows.1`

Comment: Good catch. I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76077470/6309) to include the relevant git config commands.

Comment: I'm not sure if `[remote "C"]` is required. And actually what I want is to push any branch to repo B and auto conditionally mirror to others, I might not explaine myself clear in the question.

Comment: I'm going to mark your reply as the most helpful. Thank you for your help!